# How to choose color palette for text on top of an image?

Tags: color, page-layout, palette

Im assigned to collateral, ad design, web banners, etc.

It gets frustrating when the image im gonna put a text on top of has a wide range of color. And sometimes, it gets frustrating to choose what color of the text should be.

Is there a secret to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Add a mask/shape on top of the image with solid black color.
2. Reduce opacity of that mask/shape to around 20-30% so that your image is now visible.
3. Now try to add text over it and choose the color you want from the color palette.

It should look decent now.

Comment: Usually what i do is put a gradient and the black part is where i put the text so it will be visible without the image being too dark. But pairing the color to the image is tricky for me and its getting tiring to just use black and white text.

Answer (score -1):

@user45100 Or you can do one thing. Try to reduce opacity of image itself to 30-40 % and then add text with solid dark colors. Might Help!